# viewBox misunderstanding - why the rectangle appears in the middle

Tags: css, svg

see this simple code code:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 50 200">
  <rect width="50" height="200" style="fill:blue"/>
</svg>
```

---

**expected result:**

the *viewBox* settings will perfectly crop the rectangle, then stretch it across 400x400 svg *viewPort*.
resulting in 400x400 blue square.

**actual result**

blue rectangle, in the middle of the svg *viewport*, with white marigins in the sides.

---

what did i miss?

Comment: you missed preserveAspectRatio

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html, scroll down to the "The View Box" heading and read the answer to your question